# How to export a volume as a separate render pass and composite it correctly in Photoshop?

Tags: export, transparency, volumetrics, compositing-nodes

I have one render layer with objects and one render layer with a fog volume. The objects are set to Holdout on the layer with the fog.

The combined composite output (left image) looks correct. It also looks correct if I combine the background and fog render layers using an Alpha Over node in the Blender compositor.

If I export the fog render layer and try to combine them in Photoshop, it looks like the right image instead. The fog volume becomes too transparent. This happens with any variation of png, exr, TIFF that I've tried.

What is the correct method to replicate the output of the Blender compositor in Photoshop?

[Photoshop File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R7dHE2pedos4bwd8WLvdn4iS6bi8nK4K/view?usp=sharing)

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sa6yg550XERQ1h14JBuO1rx5h6SoYPGE/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Left: Blender Compositor; Right: Photoshop]

Comment: Can you elaborate more about how you render only volumetric and how you combine them using Photoshop? I think not every one got a license of Photoshop here, so we can't help you without know how you use it in Photoshop

Comment: I attached the Blender file as well in the original post, to show the View Layers.

I’m realizing this problem is not unique to Photoshop, because of the following: If i export the fog layer as a png and import it back into the Blender compositor, the same issue arises. In other words, I combine the fog and the objects with an Alpha Over node, it looks correct when I use the fog Render Layer, and incorrect when I use the exported png of the fog. That’s why I’m wonder if there is a specific combination of export settings and/or blend modes that will solve it.

Comment: In Photoshop I’m adding the fog layer over the other one, tested with various blend modes.